# How to match 2 digits in python with string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I have following options, but all of them return full string. I need to remove date at the beginning with regex.

```
d = re.match('^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}(.*?)$', '01.10.2018Any text..')
d = re.match('^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}(.*?)$', '01.10.2018Any text..')
```

How to do that? Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the first group of the match

```
>>> d = re.match('^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}(.*?)$', '01.10.2018Any text..').group(1)
>>> print (d)
'Any text..'
```

If you are not sure, if there would be a match, you have to check it first

```
>>> s = '01.10.2018Any text..'
>>> match = re.match('^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}(.*?)$', s)
>>> d = match.group(1) if match else s
>>> print(d)
'Any text..'
```

Comment: And if there is no match... won't it return an error?

Comment: Yes. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: So the problem is i should use `group(1)` instead of `d[3]`? That's weird why I can't use array to print result.

Comment: That would also work for `99.10.2018Any text..` which is an invalid date...

Comment: Here the `.` matching any character works, however for educational purposes it would be good to escape the dot to show OP that metacharacters need escaping.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need a reluctant quantifier `?` here, it's completely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=sub#re.sub) to match the date like pattern (Note that that does not validate a date) from the start of the string `^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`  and replace with an empty string.

And as @UnbearableLightness mentioned, you have to escape the dot `\.` if you want to match it literally.

```
import re
result = re.sub(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}', '', '01.10.2018Any text..')
print(result) # Any text..
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KBEQRO76345)

Comment: That is why I added `(Note that that does not validate a date) ` to my answer.

Comment: Here the `.` matching any character works, however for educational purposes it would be good to escape the dot to show OP that metacharacters need escaping.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Ah I missed that one. Thank you for your sharp observation!

Answer (score 0):

Use a group to extract the date part:

```
d = re.match('^(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})(.*?)$', '01.10.2018Any text..')
if d:
    print(d.group(1))
    print(d.group(2))
```

Group 0 is the whole string, I added a pair of parentheses in the regex around the date. This is group 1. Group 2 is the text after which is what you're after

Comment: That would also work for `99.10.2018Any text..` which is an invalid date...